# Update manager doesn't work

Tags: updates, update-manager

often the update manager says i don't have an internet connection and stops working. I check and do have access to the internet.... I think it might have something to do with updating google chrome because it usually does this when updating chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally run in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Watch both those commands and you will find the issue.  Post back and we can debug further.

Optionally once you find the issue you can disable that software source by going into your Update Manager and clicking settings and then going into "Other Sources" if it turns out to be a non-Ubuntu issue and an application installed on Ubuntu like Google Chrome.  My Chrome install uses this URL http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/

Comment: thank you I disabled the chrome update and it is working now.

Comment: It does not work for my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to run these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in the terminal.

If you were interrupted during a previous update, your update manager might not work but these commands (if you watch them) will tell you what's wrong. Sometimes it will tell you that your files are broken or it needs to retrieve archives, or might tell you to run the `apt-get update` again, or "run with `--fix-missing`". If this happens, run the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

This will take a little while because your computer is replacing broken files and programs with archived older versions and then updating them from there.
I don't know how to format this so it actually looks like the code, but if you read it from the terminal it should work.

Honestly it's usually an issue with chrome and after you do - -fix-missing Chrome might not work for you anymore. That's why it's good to have firefox if you can.